# DNS and apache redirection

Tags: apache, dns

I'm having issues to clearly manage my website redirection. Let say that I'd like to create a invisible redirect from www.siteA.com to www.siteB.com/content. Here you have what I'd like to have:

> www.siteA.com --DNS--> www.siteB.com --Apache on siteB --> /wwww/content/siteA/

For the first part, I can do it using "CNAME" configuration at DNS level.

However, I'd like to have a kind of Apache rewrite rule on "www.siteB.com" machine in order to redirect to "/wwww/content/siteA/" **only if** we come from www.siteA.com DNS requests.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at apache virtual hosts http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ ? It does exactly what you ask for as I understood it - at least the second part.

Comment: VirtualHost entries seem to be parametrized by and IP (or donaimename) + PORT. In my case, the IP would be the IP of "siteB" but I don't know if I have access to the fact that the HTTP request comes from a DNS redirect from siteA.

Comment: Look at name based virtual hosts http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html  You can run them both on the same computer and same apache server. Both sites can resolve to the same computer hosting both (or many more) sites

Comment: I'll go through it more carefully but at first sight, after the DNS redirect, the "Name" received by Apache would be "siteB" (and there are other VirtualHost already installed in siteB so I cannot do a kind of by default configuration).

Comment: You don't need DNS redirect for this, what you need is DNS resolution to computer hosting both sites.

Comment: I think it's not doable like this. Webserver on siteB doesn't know that siteA was requested originally. A solution would be to redirect to a subdomain of siteB like siteA.siteB.com

Comment: my mistake, I would like to to a resolution, not a redirect... but still, how can i distinguish requests arriving at siteB between those from DNS resolution from siteA to regular requests to siteB ?